# Android Studio: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView')

Tags: android, xml

I will put a adview (admob) in the bottom of a webview

When I gradle sync, I get this error. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

`C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(20, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').
C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(20, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

This is my MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="danilkp1234.com.pokemondamagecalculator.MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your MainActivity.xml doesn't seem to be complete. The first LinearLayout is not beeing closed

Comment: `android:layout_above` is a **RelativeLayout** attribute. It won't work in a LinearLayout container.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
android:layout_above="@id/adView"
```

with

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
```

Just need to add '+' after '@'

Comment: No, It's not.  `+` is only for defining id  first time

Comment: So it is becuase layout is referring a view with id 'adView' but it does not actaully exist hence giving an error! correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Yea, you right too. In general this layout is messed up. `android:layout_above` is used only in relativeLayout. root `LinearLayout` tag dont have close too

Comment: Yea, how can I miss that! using android:layout_above="@+id/adView is not valid at all as its parent viewgroup is not a relative layout!

Answer (score 0):

Where is the view with the id `adView`?

Also `android:layout_above` is used for views inside a `RelativeLayout`, not `LinearLayout`. In a `RelativeLayout` views can be placed below, on top or next to each other with `android:layout_...` attributes. `LinearLayout` automatically puts views below or next to one another depending on the `android:orientation` parameter.

If you want to continue using `LinearLayout` you should remove

```
android:layout_above="@id/adView"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in 
    `android:layout_above="@id/adView"`
At first try to change 
    `@id/adView to @+id/adView.`

Also, 
    `android:layout_above=""`   is used in `RelativeLayout`, hence your LinearLayout won't affect any change. Change the parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and then add further View (having`id adView`) to affect a change.